# Is there a way to reference self azure pipeline yaml folder?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to parametrize the folder which holds the pipeline.yml file within my repository. For example, with a repo named "project-1" which has a pipeline at path "job-1-folder/azure-pipelines.yml", I would want to get "job-1-folder" in a varible. In a similar way that builtin variables work, something like "${{ Build.Pipeline.Folder }}".

I am using templates to reuse common pipelines so by now the only thing that changes is the folder which holds the code (job-1-folder in the following sample). If I can parametrize this, all pipelines will be the equal and most users won't event have to change the pipeline at all. Sample pipeline:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
      - main
  paths:
    include:
      - 'job-1-folder'
pr:
  autoCancel: false
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
      - main
  paths:
    include:
      - 'job-1-folder'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: devops
      ref: 'refs/heads/main'

extends:
  template: pipelines\dbr-job-template.yml@templates
  parameters:
    sourceFolder: 'job-1-folder'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not use Parameters in the Trigger Paths configuration, this is not supported. You must hard coded this.

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
      - main
  paths:
    include:
      - 'job-1-folder'
pr:
  autoCancel: false
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
      - main
  paths:
    include:
      - 'job-1-folder'
```

You can specify parameters and their data types in a template and pass those parameters to a pipeline. You can also use parameters outside of templates. Refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script).

Here's a sample:

```
parameters:
- name: Folderpath
  displayName: SelectPath
  type: string
  default: job-1-folder
  values:
  - job-1-folder
  - job-2-folder
  - job-3-folder

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: devops
      ref: 'refs/heads/main'

extends:
  template: pipelines\dbr-job-template.yml@templates
  parameters:
    sourceFolder: ${{ parameters.Folderpath }}
```

[image]

Comment: I was afraid of that. I just wanted to keep things simple for common users and allow them to  just copy a project template folder. I have opened an request in order to get this done if you think it would be useful https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Add-azure-pipeline-yaml-folder-as-a-pred/10238119